# How can i keep current page until the next page is fully loaded( ios UIWebview)

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

I have an app based on `UIWebview`,
When a user clicks on a URL, the default behavior is to immediately show a blank page and stay waiting until the page is loaded

Is that possible to keep the current page until the next page is loaded?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Use NSTimer  & Activity indicator for waiting till the page is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm curious as to the necessity for this funtionality and I'd probably agree with [Chandra Vaghasiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4613156/chandra-vaghasiya)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014934/how-can-i-keep-current-page-until-the-next-page-is-fully-loaded-ios-uiwebview#comment53853165_33014934).

Having said that this is possible.

1. Make your view controller the delegate of the `UIWebView`.
2. In the `webViewDidStartLoad:` method, take a snapshot of the web view and add the resulting view above the web view in the view hierarchy.
3. In the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` and `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` methods simply hide the snapshotted view.

Example code:

```
@interface ViewController () <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *snapshotView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    self.snapshotView = [self.webView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];

    self.snapshotView.frame = self.webView.frame;

    [self.view insertSubview:self.snapshotView
                aboveSubview:self.webView];

    self.snapshotView.hidden = NO;

    // THIS IS JUST FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES SO
    // YOU CAN SEE THE LOADING HAPPENING BEHIND
    // THE SNAPSHOT VIEW
    self.snapshotView.alpha = 0.8;

    NSLog(@"Display snapshot");
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    self.snapshotView.hidden = YES;
    NSLog(@"Hide snapshot");
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    self.snapshotView.hidden = YES;
    NSLog(@"Hide snapshot due to error");
}

@end
```